# What are the Bluetooth profiles supported by the Nexus 7 (KitKat)?

Tags: bluetooth, nexus-7, 4.4-kitkat

I would think this is a simple question, but I am not finding the answer after searching.

What are the Bluetooth profiles supported by KitKat on the Nexus 7?

Answer (score 2):

The full list of profiles is:

- Advanced Audio Distribution Profile (A2DP)
- Headset Profile (HSP)
- Health Device Profile (HDP)
- Health Thermometer profile (HTP)
- Heart Rate Profile (HRP)
- Human Interface Device Profile (HID, InputDevice)
- Message Access Profile (MAP)
- Personal Area Networking Profile (PAN)
- Audio/Video Remote Control Profile (AVRCP)
- Generic Attribute (Gatt, HOGP, BTLE): Bluetooth 4.0 required
- Generic Attribute Server (Gatt Server, BTLE): Bluetooth 4.0 required

Comment: Wow, this is interesting! How did you get this list?

Comment: Compiled it from multiple sources.

Answer (score 0):

> New Bluetooth profiles
>
> Android 4.4 support for two new Bluetooth profiles to let apps support
>   a broader range of low-power and media interactions. Bluetooth HID
>   over GATT (HOGP) gives apps a low-latency link with low-power
>   peripheral devices such as mice, joysticks, and keyboards. Bluetooth
>   MAP lets your apps exchange messages with a nearby device, for example
>   an automotive terminal for handsfree use or another mobile device. As
>   an extension to Bluetooth AVRCP 1.3, users can now set absolute volume
>   on the system from their Bluetooth devices.
>
> Platform support for HOGP, MAP, and AVRCP is built on the Bluedroid
>   Bluetooth stack introduced by Google and Broadcom in Android 4.2.
>   Support is available right away on Nexus devices and other
>   Android-compatible devices that offer compatible Bluetooth
>   capabilities.

Source: [Android KitKat](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html#44-bluetooth)

Comment: What I am looking for is the complete set of profiles for the Nexus 7 running KitKat; not just the new KitKat introductions.